# How to create a pkpass file in Visual Studio, in widows

Tags: pkpass

I wonder if there is a way to create a pkpass file in windows from visual studio, or is there a way to generate its structure and change the information for testing?

I've been looking at how to make this structure manually, but I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new project in Visual Studio and choose the type of project
   you want to create. Download the pasKit framework from Apple's
   developer website.
2. Add the PassKit framework to your project by right-clicking on the
   project in the Solution Explorer and selecting "Add Reference".  In
   the Reference Manager dialog box, browse to the location where you
   downloaded the Pass-Kit framework and add it to your project.
3. Create the pkpass file structure by creating a new directory with
   the ext (.pkpass) This dir will contain the files and folders that
   make up the pkpass file.
4. Write the necessary code to generate the contents of the pkpass
   file, such as the pass.json file, imgs, and other rsrcs. You can use
   the PassKit classes to create the pass.json file and add the
   required fields, such as the pass type identifier, serial number,
   and authentication token.
5. Once you have created the files and folders, compress them into a
   zip file. Rename the this zip file with extension".pkpass" to create
   the final file.
6. To test the pkpass file, add it to the Passbook app on whatever
   iphone you have

Comment: Hello Hamza, All this I can run from Windows and later to test it I can do it from an Android application?

Comment: I was wrong as such, is Visual Studio Code, is the framework installed the same?

Comment: @CamiloGonzález Yes, u can create a .pkpass file on a Windows computer, and then use it to test your PassKit on android . To make the .pkpass file, u will need a tool like PassKit.net/ PassSlot. After you've made it, you can move it to your android device and use a some SDK like WalletPasses to show the pass to users in your Android app. these passkit are ussually used with Apple's Wallet app instead of android so there might be some differences